# Simulating Repository logic by Autowiring a bean from an interface that extends another interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I want to simulate the JpaRepositry logic by Autowiring the bean from another interface that extends the interface that the bean is implementing

### [image: design describing what i did]

the first interface :

```
public interface Test {
 String getBlaBla();
 String getWhatever();
  }
```

the bean:

```
    @Component
    public class TestImplementation implements Test {
    @Override
    public String getBlaBla() {
        return "BLA BLA";
    }

    @Override
    public String getWhatever() {
        return "WHATEVER";
    }
}
```

the second interface :

```
public interface TestTwo extends Test {
}
```

but I had a problem **Autowiring** the bean from **TestTwo** interface :

```
    @Autowired
    private TestTwo test;
```

I had problem of **Could not autowire. No beans of 'TestTwo' type found**

I did try to add **@NoRepositoryBean** over the interface **TestTwo**  but I kept having the same thing

Comment: you are using intelj?

Answer (score 0):

> I did try to add @NoRepositoryBean over the interface TestTwo but I
>   kept having the same thing

`TestTwo` is not a Spring repository interface, so it is ignored by Spring concerning this point.

The [`@NoRepositoryBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/NoRepositoryBean.html) javadoc states indeed  :

> Annotation to exclude repository interfaces from being picked up and
>   thus in consequence getting an instance being created.

I will never work with your own interfaces out of the box.
Interfaces that extend `JpaRepository` are handled by Spring when the container start to give to them an implementation.
`JpaRepository` is a special interface handled by Spring.
In your case Spring doesn't handle the `TestTwo` interface in the same way.

To achieve such a thing or at least close things you should interest to CGLIB or AOP with Spring.